# Why bad substitution?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to get a value from awk:
I try $(), it shows bad substitution:

```
a=${awk 'BEGIN { last=substr("[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End",10,23); print last}'}  
bash: ${awk 'BEGIN { last=substr("[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End",10,23); print last}'}: bad substitution
```

but if I use ``, it works well:

```
a=`awk 'BEGIN { last=substr("[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End",10,23); print last}'`
```

The code in awk works well.
I'm trying to use awk to match the last "[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End" like strings from a file. And the code is used to try.

Comment: " I try $(), it shows bad substitution" but I don't see `$()`.

Comment: I see.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not valid so, you have to create variable using `myvar=$( .... )`, whereas  basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`

From

```
a=${awk 'BEGIN { last=substr("[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End",10,23); print last}'}
```

To

```
a=$(awk 'BEGIN { last=substr("[Import][2017-10-30 02:30:45 UTC] End",10,23); print last}')
```